# El diciembre del año pasado

Tags: traducción

How do I say 'December of last year' in Spanish?

> El diciembre del año pasado fuimos a la playa a divertirnos.

Are there any alternatives for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

> En diciembre del año pasado fuimos a la playa a divertirnos.

you could either, just drop *del año*:

> El pasado diciembre fuimos a la playa a divertirnos.

or drop that and permute:

> El diciembre pasado fuimos a la playa a divertirnos.

Or just:

> El último diciembre fuimos a la playa a divertirnos.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> En diciembre del año pasado fuimos a la playa a divertirnos.
>
> El año pasado, en diciembre, fuimos a la playa a divertirnos.
>
> El pasado mes de diciembre fuimos a la playa a divertirnos. *(just in case you are saying this the next year)*

Comment: *Diciembre* va con minúscula.

Comment: Cierto es, dejé copiado lo que tenía. ¡Gracias!